# Build a dynamic command from hosts in Ansible

Tags: solr, command, jinja2, apache-zookeeper, ansible

I am working on an Ansible deploy script to connect a solr node to a running zookeeper ensemble. The command to link the solr config to zookeeper looks like this:

```
solr/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost 33.33.33.30:2181,33.33.33.31:2181,33.33.33.32:2181 -cmd upconfig -confdir solr/solr/collection1/conf -confname solr_config
```

I want to make the command as dynamic as possible - so I want to pull the zookeeper hosts from my inventory file. I can do it when I know there is always 3, but I would like to have the command adjust depending on how many are listing. I have tried with Ansibles `with` command - but I can't get it to work because I don't need a comma after the last host.

Here is my inventory file:

```
[zookeeper]
33.33.33.30
33.33.33.31
33.33.33.32

[solr]
33.33.33.33
33.33.33.34
33.33.33.35
```

And here is my Ansible task without a loop:

```
- name: SOLR | Upload Configs To Zookeeper
  command: "{{ solr.home }}/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost {{groups.zookeeper[0] }}:{{ zookeeper.port }}, {{ groups.zookeeper[1] }}:{{ zookeeper.port }}, {{ groups.zookeeper[2] }}:{{ zookeeper.port }} -cmd upconfig -confdir {{ solr.home }}/solr/{{ solr.collection_name }}/conf -confname {{ solr.config_name }}"
  when: inventory_hostname == groups.solr[0]
```

And idea how to make this dynamic to the number of zookeeper hosts in the inventory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your loop you can prevent the comma after the last item with the [loop controls of Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#loop-controls):

```
{%- if not loop.last %}, {% endif -%}
```

But this is a more sexy solution:

```
{{ groups.zookeeper | join(":%d, " | format(zookeeper.port)) }}:{{ zookeeper.port }}
```

So we [`join`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#join) your array elements together with the glue of `port`+comma. Since the last element will therefore not have the `port`, we output the `port` again after the first expression.

Comment: thanks for showing two ways; take small issue with calling join-plus-dangle sexy

Answer (score 1):

Just a side comment: if **SolrCloud** has been already started pointing to the **ZooKeeper** ensemble, then the **solr create** command can be used for uploading the configuration to ZooKeeper in addition to create the corresponding Solr cores.

Note: If you only want to upload files to ZooKeeper, without creating the corresponding Solr cores, then you should keep executing **zkcli.sh** as in  the example shown in the question.

Ansible task for creating cores in SolrCloud and uploading configuration to ZooKeeper:

```
- name: create solr cores
  command: /opt/solr/bin/solr create -c {{ item }} -d /tmp/solr/{{ item }}
  with_items:
    - my_collection
    - another_collection
  become: yes
  become_user: solr
```

The above Ansible task assumes the following:

- The following directory structure is available:

  ```
  /tmp/solr
  ├── my_collection
  │   └── conf
  │       ├── schema.xml
  ├── another_collection
  │   └── conf
  │       ├── schema.xml
  ```
- The Solr distribution was extrated into **/opt/solr**.
- The user **solr** started Solr in the machine.

See also:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Taking+Solr+to+Production

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+ZooKeeper+to+Manage+Configuration+Files